# JFrame Bug workaround

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I discovered something weird while programming an application:
I wanted a JFrame to be placed over the entire screen. It works perfectly with this code:

```
public class NativeFunctions extends JFrame {

    public NativeFunctions() throws HeadlessException {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeFunctions n = new NativeFunctions();
    }
}
```

When I just change the line of code, that sets the color to a color with an alpha value, the things start get get weird:

```
public class NativeFunctions extends JFrame {

    public NativeFunctions() throws HeadlessException {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 20));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeFunctions n = new NativeFunctions();
    }
}
```

Starting the first application, the JFrame opens and covers up the screen - as expected. Try to move the mouse in the top left, top right, bottom right or bottom left corner and press a mouse key. Nothing will happen.
Do the same thing with the second application (with the alpha value) and the click will be registered. But this happens only in the outermost corner!

Can you reproduce this and would you say it is a bug? Do you have an idea for a workaround?

Edit: Also important: For all transparency values the same! Only works at the outermost corner, not in the middle of the application, so the mouse click is not generally passed by!

Comment: `and the click will be registered.` - how do you know? What does that mean to you. You haven't added a MouseListener to the frame so how can you say it is registered. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your statement.

Comment: @camickr I posted a complete minimal example. Thats it. If you run it the problem should be reproduced. With "registered" I didn't mean the event of the JFrame but the normal action of the operating system like if there was no Frame over the screen.

Comment: And you still haven't defined "outermost corner". How can people test if we are not sure what your mean. Are we talking maybe 4-5 pixels around the edge of the desktop? Is this maybe an area reserved for the border around the frame. Or is it a bigger area. I tried clicking 1 pixel in each corner and noticed no difference in behaviour.

Comment: @camickr I marked the positions I talk about here: https://photouploads.com/image/Ejyk
It is the 1 px outermost corner where you have to click

Answer (score 0):

> (with the alpha value) and the click will be registered. But this happens only in the outermost corner!

You need to define "registered".

In my case, nothing happens, no matter where I click because all mouse events are just passed to the frame, but there is no listener added to the frame so I have no cue that anything just happened.

This is what I expect to happen with partial transparency (alpha values between 1 - 255).

However, with an alpha value of 0, then the mouse event is ignore by the Swing application and is passed to the desktop.

So, for example, if I click on the bottom/left where the Windows Start button is I see the Start menu popup.

If I click anywhere else then the application I click on is now activated and becomes the active window.

There is no distinction between "outermost corner" (however you define that?) and clicking in the center of the screen.

> Do you have an idea for a workaround?

I'm guessing you want to prevent the mouse event from being passed to the destop when you have an alpha value between 1 - 255.

Did you try adding a MouseListener to the frame?

Maybe you can try adding a `GlassPane` to the frame and add a MouseListener to the GlassPane?

Comment: The is not true at all! As I wrote above, the mouse click is only working  at the outermost corner! Anywhere else it doesn't! And also this is not 100% transparent, works for all transparency values.

Comment: @TheProgrammer: What OS/L&F?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland Windows 10 Education, newest Java Version

Comment: When using partial transparency (an alpha value between 1 - 255), I can click anywhere and nothing happens. This is because the events are passed to the frame. So basically the desktop becomes frozen because I can't click on anything. When using complete transparency (alpha value of 0), then the event is handled by the applications under the frame. For example if I click on the "Start" button, at the bottom/left the Start menu is displayed. Or if I click anywhere else in the window, the application I click on will now have focus.

Comment: @camickr You also seem to not be able to read! I said It does not do anything wherever I click, except for the outermost corners! Just run the code and try...

Comment: I did run the code! Did you read the answer/comment? What I have described is the way it has worked for as long as I can remember. I have used various version of the JDK over the years and am currently usingJDK8 on Windows 7.  If it doesn't work this way for you then it is an LAF/version/platform issue.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a while of testing I found out what the "bug" was. There is no Bug in Java but strangely it had to do with Netbeans. Whenever I started the program from Netbeans it did not work (what I described in my question happened) but when I started the .jar file it worked out perfectly!